# Reactjs nested routes is not redirect to child screen

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

At menu, I have Albums. If user click the Albums, AlbumsPage(All of Album) will show.
If user click the Album, AlbumPage will show. So I want my Albums menu is still selected.

But If I click Album, route is not working. Still showing AlbumsPage. I don't see no error. What is wrong with my nested route?

Paths

```
const paths = {
  home: "/",

  albums: "/albums",
  getAlbums: () => `/albums`,
  album: "album/:albumId",
  getAlbum: (albumId) => `album/${albumId}`,
};

export default paths;
```

Rotes

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path={paths.albums} element={<AlbumsPage />}>
      <Route path={paths.album} element={<AlbumPage />}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
```

Comment: Can you also add these `AlbumsPage` and `AlbumPage` components? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Drew Reese, Actually, If I move the AlbumPage route to outside of AlbumsPage, both page is working. But Albums menu selection is gone. That's why I don't add the page.

Comment: Is that what you want? For `AlbumsPage` to be rendered on `path="/albums"` and for `AlbumPage` to be rendered on `path="/album/###"`? Or do you want `AlbumsPage` to be rendered on `path="/albums"` and remain on the screen when `AlbumPage` to be rendered on `path="/albums/album/###"`?

Comment: I want AlbumsPage to be rendered on path="/albums" and AlbumPage to be rendered on path="/albums/album/###" but I don't want AlbumPage remain on the screen when user click Album. For Album page's path is no specific. As long as menu is still selected, I am ok :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want:

1. `AlbumsPage` to be rendered exclusively on `path="/albums"`
2. `AlbumPage` to be rendered exclusively on `path="/albums/album/###"`

You can move `AlbumsPage` into an index route so that is it matched and rendered when the parent `Route` component's path is exactly `paths.albums`, or `"/albums"`. `AlbumPage` will continue to be rendered on the relative path `paths.album`, or resolved as `"/albums/album/###"`. By not specifying an `element` prop for the parent `Route` an `Outlet` component will be rendered by default for the nested `Route` components to be rendered into.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path={paths.albums}>                            // "/albums" `Outlet` is rendered
    <Route index element={<AlbumsPage />} />             // "/albums"
    <Route path={paths.album} element={<AlbumPage />} /> // "/albums/album/###"
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: thanks you so much for your answer. Yes, it is exactly what I want. It is working now.